# Optional function argument that is specified as a trait instead of a concrete type

Tags: rust, enet

I have been watching Rust for the past few months but I just started into an actual project. I am not sure if the terminology in the title is correct. Please let me know how it can be corrected.

I am writing a rust wrapper around the ENet library (http://enet.bespin.org). My goal is to keep the rust API as similar to the C API as possible except to refactor functions that take C style handle pointers into member functions of structure objects. I want to keep the API similar so that the official C documentation will apply equally well to the rust wrapper.

ENet exposes a single function to create either a client host or a server host. When creating a server you pass a pointer to an IP Address structure to the function. When creating a client you pass NULL.

I am trying to emulate that behavior using the `ToSocketAddr` trait and `Option` but I am running into problems using them in conjunction.

This is a reduced example of what I am trying to do:

```
use std::io::net::ip::ToSocketAddr;

fn create_host<A: ToSocketAddr>(addr: Option<A>) {
    match addr {
        Some(a) => println!("Address is {}. Return a server host object.",a.to_socket_addr()),
        None    => println!("no address... Return a client.")
    };
}


fn main() {
    create_host(Some("localhost:12345"));
    create_host(None);
}
```

The first call to `create_host()` works like a charm. The second call however will not compile.

Rustc returns

```
error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations required
```

I am guessing that error is occurring because `None` doesn't provide any resolution to the generic `A`. I tried the following but this doesn't work either because `ToSocketAddr` does not implement the trait `core::kinds::Sized`.

```
fn create_host(addr: Option<ToSocketAddr>) {
    ...
}
```

Is there a way I can do this or do I need to take a different approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fn main() {
    create_host(Some("localhost:12345"));
    create_host(None::<&str>);
}
```

I've chosen `&str` here as it is the same type as on the first call, so that the compiler wouldn't generate another monomorphized version of the generic function. You could choose any type that implements `ToSocketAddr`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I haven't seen that syntax applied to `None` in any examples before now. Do you have any links that explain exactly why/how it works?

Comment: See [Paths](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#paths) and [Generic functions](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#generic-functions) in the Rust Reference. `None` is not a generic function, but rather a generic/polymorphic constant, but the type argument list syntax still applies.

Comment: Thanks, those helped.