# Why does the rust compiler require a type annotation for Option<&impl Trait>?

Tags: rust

Given this MCVE:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", foo(None));
}

trait Trait {}
struct Struct {}
impl Trait for Struct {}

fn foo(maybe_trait: Option<&impl Trait>) -> String {
    return "hello".to_string();
}
```

The rust compiler is not happy:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src\main.rs:2:20
  |
2 |     println!("{}", foo(None));
  |                    ^^^ cannot infer type for `impl Trait`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0282`.
```

Using type annotations makes this compile:

```
fn main() {
    let nothing: Option<&Struct> = None;
    println!("{}", foo(nothing));
}

trait Trait {}
struct Struct {}
impl Trait for Struct {}

fn foo(maybe_trait: Option<&impl Trait>) -> String {
    return "hello".to_string();
}
```

If we use `Trait` instead of `Struct` in the type annotation, there is a bit more information given to us:

```
warning: trait objects without an explicit `dyn` are deprecated
 --> src\main.rs:2:26
  |
2 |     let nothing: Option<&Trait> = None;
  |                          ^^^^^ help: use `dyn`: `dyn Trait`
  |
  = note: #[warn(bare_trait_objects)] on by default

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn Trait` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src\main.rs:3:20
  |
3 |     println!("{}", foo(nothing));
  |                    ^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `dyn Trait`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
note: required by `foo`
 --> src\main.rs:10:1
  |
10| fn foo(maybe_trait: Option<&impl Trait>) -> String {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

I understand this as "You shall not use a trait here, because then I do not know how much memory I need to allocate for this parameter".

**But why is that relevant when I am passing `None`?**
Of course, passing any concrete instance of a type implementing `Trait` (i.e. `Struct`) is okay to the compiler.

---

Sidenote:
I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53769384/2550406) on the difference between `&dyn Trait` and `&impl Trait`. I'm unsure when to use which, but since my program does compile with `&impl Trait` (when using type annotations as above) it seems like the safe choice.

If instead we make the function parameter be of type `Option<&dyn Trait>`, my program compiles without type annotations within `main()`:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", foo(None));
}

trait Trait {}
struct Struct {}
impl Trait for Struct {}

fn foo(maybe_trait: Option<&dyn Trait>) -> String {
    return "hello".to_string();
}
```

---

```
$ cargo --version
cargo 1.37.0 (9edd08916 2019-08-02)  

$ cat Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "rdbug"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["redacted"]
edition = "2018"
```

Comment: It's because the compiler must *deduce* types, it can't *guess* them even if there is only one to guess from (except in certain specific scenarios not including this one). `None` could be `Option<Struct>::None` or `Option::<AnotherTypeImplementingTrait>::None`. `impl trait` in argument position works like generics, so the compiler has to know what version of `foo` to instantiate, and `None` could be anything.

Comment: See for example, [Is there a way to hint to the compiler to use some kind of default generic type when using Option::None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58593042/is-there-a-way-to-hint-to-the-compiler-to-use-some-kind-of-default-generic-type) (all the answers) and [Optional function argument that is specified as a trait instead of a concrete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283507/optional-function-argument-that-is-specified-as-a-trait-instead-of-a-concrete-ty). Does one of those answer your question or are you still unsure?

Comment: @trentcl Does that mean the compiler is not able to consider types like `Option` and realize that a generic type does not matter for the use case?

Comment: it does matter, the size of the Option depend of the type that impl the trait.

Comment: @Stargateur So an `Option<HugeThing>` would always take up huge amounts of memory even if it were `None::HugeThing`? Fair enough, but if it were an `Option<&HugeThing>`, that should not matter anymore. All adresses are of the same size, no matter if they point to a trait object or struct, right?

Comment: I think you're missing that `foo::HugeThing` might behave differently than `foo::OtherThing` *even when passed `None`*, and the compiler has to know to use the right one.

Comment: (Also, not all references are the same size because references to unsized types are fat pointers, but even if they were, the compiler still won't pick a type for you.)

Comment: I just woke up with the thought "Wait! References are fat pointers sometimes". So Thanks for confirming @trentcl. But Re: "different behaviour when None", that would only matter if the function did a type check on the `Option<T>` or called a function where the distinction matters. Am I right that some such cases could be optimized if the references were guaranteed to have the same size?

Comment: Either way, I think I'd accept your answer :) Bonus appreciation if you could explain what kind of info an unsized type reference contains

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
fn foo(maybe_trait: Option<&impl Trait>) -> String {
```

is just syntactic sugar for this:

```
fn foo<T: Trait>(maybe_trait: Option<&T>) -> String {
```

Which means that the compiler will generate many `foo` functions, one for every `T` (type implementing `Trait`) that you are going to use it with. So even if you call it with `None`, the compiler needs to know which is the `T` in that case, so it can pick/generate the right function.

The way `Option<T>` type is represented in memory depends on how the `T` type is represented. The compiled assembly of the function `foo` depends on that. For different `T` the resulting assembly may look differently. (For example the enum tag that defines whether it is `Some` or `None` may be at different byte offset. It may use different registers, it may decide differently whether to unroll loops, inline functions, vectorize, ...) This is the strength of static dispatch - even that you write code with lot of abstraction, you get code fully optimized for the concrete types you actually use.

With the upcoming [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1210) feature you can actually manually write different implementation of `foo` for different subsets of `T`, so it is really important for the compiler to know which `foo` are you calling. Each may do something different with `None`.

---

On the other hand this:

```rust
fn foo(maybe_trait: Option<&dyn Trait>) -> String {
```

Means that there is **exactly one** function `foo` that takes Option containing a fat pointer to some type implementing `Trait`. If you call some method on `maybe_trait` inside the function, the call goes thru dynamic dispatch.

Since there is exactly one function `foo`, you don't have to say anything about the type when using `None`, there is only one.

But dynamic dispatch comes at cost - this one function is not optimized for any specific `T`, it works with every `T` dynamically.

Comment: Thanks! Together with the comments by @trenctl this is perfect. I'll just wait a little before accepting so that he would get a chance to write an answer as well, since he explained some good points as well

Comment: @lucidbrot Thanks, but unless there's something significant in my comments you think is not explained in this answer, I'll let michalsrb have the checkmark :) Glad I was able to help!

Comment: This finally made it click for me, great answer.